# Use getter in CriteriaBuilder query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am trying to use a getter into a criteriaQuery.

I have a Translation class and a Theme class. I want to search for a theme with is transalted value, not the translation key.

Here is my code :

```
@Entity
public class Translation implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6216704909713037946L;
    static final String DEFAULT_LOCALE = "EN";
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @NaturalId
    private String code;

    private String locale;

    private String value;

    public Translation() {}

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static String geTranslatedValue(Map<String, Translation> translations) {
        if(translations.containsKey(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getCountry()))
            return translations.get(LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getCountry()).getValue();
        else if(translations.containsKey(Translation.DEFAULT_LOCALE))
            return translations.get(Translation.DEFAULT_LOCALE).getValue();
        return null;
    }
}


@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Theme implements Serializable{
    private Map<String, Translation> names;

    private String name;

    public Theme() {
        this.names = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @JoinColumn(name = "code", referencedColumnName = "name")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKey(name = "locale")
    @JsonIgnore
    public Map<String, Translation> getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(Map<String, Translation> names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return Translation.geTranslatedValue(this.names);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And in my Dao I try to get my theme by name.

```
criteriaList.add(builder.like(themeRoot.get("name"), "%val%"));
```

But the comparison does not use the name, it uses the code of the translation even with the use of `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jpa metamodel by adding below to your dependencies

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You can now use the generated jpa metamodel classes like below

```
builder.like(themRoot.get(Theme_.name), val);
```

see section 2.4 here: 
[https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)